# Postman Azure support - Specify tenant

Tags: azure, azure-devops, postman, azure-api-management

I was looking at postman integration with Azure API Management and Azure DevOps.
https://blog.postman.com/postman-integration-for-azure-devops-users/
https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/importing-an-api/

They both look very interesting but I see no way to specify the Azure Tenant to which I want to connect to.
It simply defaults to my "home" tenant (the one where my login is tied to)
It's very common to have access to multiple Azure tenants and Azure-connected DevOps and I would like to know if anybody knows how to specify the tenant?

Comment: The only way is while importing the API from Postman in APIM gateway > log in with the user from another tenant in your subscription. This way another tenant will be selected by default

Comment: Thanks, that is a possible workaround but requires a user from the "other" tenant and that is not an option. I have created an issue in Postman github

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to select the tenant while importing API gateway in Postman, One option is to Login with a User account from different tenant like below:-

***APIM:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Azure Devops:-***

Make sure the user account you are using to sign in for Azure Devops API is connected to your Azure AD tenant and Azure Devops as an user. If your Azure Devops account is connected to your Azure AD tenant, The user will be automatically routed to your Devops organization.

[image]

Make sure the user you are trying to sign in with is connected to the specific directory.

[image]